# SQL Count Lines and Inner join

Tags: sql-server, count, report, inner-join, builder

I have this query :

```
select s.LastState
      ,count(s.LastState) as sumS
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
        on t1.ID = t2.ID
    join (select LastState
                ,count(LastState) as sum
          from table1
          where ID = X
            and LastState = 1
             or LastState = 2
          group by LastState
         ) s
        on s.LastState = t1.LastState
group by s.LastState
```

This returns the number of both state and I'd like to have the sum of both my counts.

Currently I see my first line with let's admit

10 state 1 and 5 state 2 for my ID X

and I'd like to see 15 (sum of counts for both states).

Comment: Please show sample data and desired result.  Don't describe it.

Comment: To get the total sum simply remove the `group by` clause.

Comment: sample data : -line 1 : 10 -line 2 : 5. What I want : -line 1 : 15

Comment: Without the group by clause I have the error message "s.LastState is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select --s.LastState
      LastState='LastState1and2'
      , count(s.LastState) as sumS
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
        on t1.ID = t2.ID
    join (select LastState
                ,count(LastState) as sum
          from table1
          where ID = X
            and LastState = 1
             or LastState = 2
          group by LastState
         ) s
        on s.LastState = t1.LastState
--group by s.LastState
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, really, you're a genius ! :) But I still have a problem, here is my new post if you want to take a look... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746714/retrieve-multiple-sum-columns-of-sub-queries